# Adjust ListBox items width based on its content

Tags: wpf, xaml, uniformgrid

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid   Rows="1" >                    
            </UniformGrid>                    
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBoxItem HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">listbox item 1</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 2</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 3</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 4</ListBoxItem>
    <ListBoxItem>listbox item 5</ListBoxItem>
</ListBox>
```

I have added `ListBoxItem`s as above and used `UniformGrid` to display it. but I can't achieve content based width for each of the list box item. I have tried `HorizontalContentAlignment` as `Stretch` and `Auto` width properties. Nothing happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `HorizontalAlignment` instead of `HorizontalContentAlignment`.

```
<ListBoxItem HorizontalAlignment="Left">listbox item 1</ListBoxItem>
```

If you want to set the alignment for all items, consider creating an item container style.

```
<ListBox ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
   <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left"/>
      </Style>
   </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
   <!-- ...your code. -->
</ListBox>
```

Please note that the default value for [`HorizontalAlignment`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.horizontalalignment?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=net-5.0) is already `Stretch`, so you will not see a difference there. Furthermore, there is no `Auto`. The possible values are `Left`, `Right`, `Center` and `Stretch`. All values except for `Stretch` will size to the content.